# How to create a smartphone template in PhotoShop or similar?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mockup

In order to provide prototyping templates, I would like to create a smartphone, tablet, and notebook template as raster graphics. There are many tutorials on YouTube which, unfortunately, start with what I would like to have as a result, for example [How to create an iPhone X Mockup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BduKPWc9pw).

Do you know of a tutorial to create “empty” frames of devices in the first place?

Photoshop is not a must-have-requirement. Inkscape or any other open software would be even more welcome.

Comment: You are aware you can easily find free PSD files of smartphones and tables and skip this part where you struggle to do what's already been made ?

Comment: Can you recommend a specific template that is free to use and shows only the frontal device frame with everything else transparent? That would be great, thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you need specifically, but go to Behance and look up "iphone mockup" or "ipad mockup" and you will get a lot of variations, some paid, but many of them for free, in PSD format. Most likely with transparent or removable backgrounds, if they're in PSD format.

Comment: erm... https://www.mockupworld.co/free/category/iphone/?s=iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a photograph of a device to create a mockup/template, either one you have taken yourself, or a stock photograph, and simply modify it in Photoshop.

Here's an example. Use the Quick selection tool, select  the inside of the screen, and then fill it white.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many free sites where you can find free mockups.
Like

[Mockups Studio](https://mockuuups.studio/)

[Pixeden](https://www.pixeden.com/)

[Mockupworld](https://www.mockupworld.co/)

and many others you can just simply download templates from here as per your choice.

or the second method is you can simply use the masking technique.
Follow these steps

> 1. Take one image containing any mobile.

[image]

> 2. Make the selection using the `polygonal lasso tool`, after making the selection press `CTRL+J` key to make a new selection layer.

[image: Image2]

> Take your screen that you want to put inside that selection and mask it using the `create clipping mask method`

[image: Image3]